# Why does appending a textarea only work with .text and not .val?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Slowly working up my javascript and jquery skills right now and I had been attempting to reset a textarea with .val('') and found that I could not append to it after I had reset it.

```
var console = $('#console');

function Initialize(data){
    console.text(data);
};

function AddText(data){
    console.append(data);
};

function clearConsole(){
    console.val('');
};
```

Now if I change `console.text(data)` to `console.val(data)` then I cannot append at all, rather I can only set the value. Now I also know there are more methods of getting the text from the textarea, such as `.value()`, but I haven't messed around with that much because I got my code working by using `.text('')` instead of `.val('')`

But I ran into some really strange behavior that is easier to just show instead of type out a description:

```js
var ta, tb, tc;

$(document).ready(function() {
  ta = $('#ta');
  tb = $('#tb');
  tc = $('#tc');
});

//first textarea
function AddText() {
  if (ta.text()) {
    ta.append(Math.random() + "\n");
  } else {
    ta.text(Math.random() + "\n");
  }
};

function ClearText() {
  ta.text('');
}

//second textarea
function AddVal() {
  tb.append(Math.random() + "\n");
};

function ClearVal() {
  tb.val('');
}

//third textarea
function AddVal2() {
  if (tc.val()) {
    tc.append(Math.random() + "\n");
    alert('Append is being called, but not appending.');
  } else {
    tc.val(Math.random() + "\n");
  }
};

function ClearVal2() {
  tc.val('');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Using .text to initialize the textarea allows .append and clearing</p>
<textarea readonly cols=50 rows=5 placeholder="First textarea : A" id="ta"></textarea>
<br>
<button type="button" id="AddText" onclick="AddText()">Add Text</button>
<button type="button" id="ClearText" onclick="ClearText()">Clear</button>
<br>
<p>Using .val to initialize the textarea does not allow .append after clearing</p>
<textarea readonly cols=50 rows=5 placeholder="Second textarea : B" id="tb"></textarea>
<br>
<button type="button" id="AddVal" onclick="AddVal()">Add Text</button>
<button type="button" id="ClearVal" onclick="ClearVal()">Clear</button>
<br>
<p>Using .val to initialize the textarea with the extra checks doesn't append at all.
<br>An alert is generated to show the append is called, but no appending occurs.</p>
<textarea readonly cols=50 rows=5 placeholder="Third textarea : C" id="tc"></textarea>
<br>
<button type="button" id="AddVal2" onclick="AddVal2()">Add Text</button>
<button type="button" id="ClearVal2" onclick="ClearVal2()">Clear</button>
```

Can someone explain to me this behavior and the best practice to use? Or is it all really the same and it's just up to preference? Thanks.

**EDIT:** [Bonus jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxy4382n/9/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why `.append` isn't allowed after `.val` but you shouldn't be using `.append`. `.append` is for appending *elements* not text.

`.text` is for setting the innerHTML and escaping that HTML so that it appears as plain text.

`.val` is what you should be using, even for textareas.

To append with .val, just do

```
$el.val($el.val() + "\nnew content");
```

Also, it should be noted that your choice of variable name, `console`, will hide the global variable by the same name (lets you log to your F12 Developer Tools).

Comment: I should have mentioned this in my answer as well, got sidetracked with the weird behavior append caused.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer because 1) explained why `.append` is not appropriate 2) provide a solution which makes the broken examples work.
For the record, to make the second and third code example work, `tb.val(tb.val() + Math.random() + "\n");` works as expected! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Your appends are working, you just aren't seeing them because of a weird quirk. The quirk is that `append` sets the `text` property but if you clear the `val` the `text` will no longer be visible.

You can see this for yourself by adding `console.log(tb.text(), tb.val())` to `AddVal()`. Adding similar logs to the other functions may be helpful as well.

The really interesting question here is **why** does it work that way, and that I'm afraid I'll have to leave to someone with deeper knowledge.

Comment: Definitely did seem like an odd quirk and just couldn't figure out what that quirk was! Changing the lines that use `.val()` to `tb.val(tb.val() + Math.random() + "\n");` for example makes them work though and is what I think the correct implementation should be.

Answer (score 1):

input is an html field with a single value:

```
<input value='whatever' />
```

but textarea has content:

```
<textarea>this is the content that can be added to</textarea>
```

So loosely think that textarea is a block of text which can be added to, input is a variable which can be defined

Comment: He isn't using any inputs so this isn't really relevant.